# Do other Puranas besides Brahmanda Purana claim parity with the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahmanda-purana

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc243151.html

> 8. That Prajāpati (Lord of all creatures), Lord (Brahmā) recounted to Vasiṣṭha[1], **the entire Purāṇa that is on a par with the Vedas** and the main theme of which is the real state of the universe.

> 9. The holy sage Vasiṣṭha taught to his grandson, Parāśara, the son of Śakti, this sacred (Purāṇa) which is the nectar of the knowledge of reality.

> 10. The holy lord Parāśara, at first, taught sage Jātukarṇya **this divine Purāṇa that is on a par with the Vedas.**

> 11. After learning the Purāṇa, the learned Jātukarṇya[2] transferred the knowledge of the supreme, eternal Brahman to Dvaipāyana[3].

> 12. Dvaipāyana was delighted thereby. That self-controlled sage passed on the knowledge of that extremely wonderful Purāṇa the content of which was the knowledge of the real state of the world.

> 13-14. For the sake of propagating it in the worlds, he taught **this Purāṇa which is (highly esteemed) like the Vedas** and which contains many topics, to Jaimini, Sumantu, Vaiśampāyana, Pailava who was the fourth among them and Lomaharṣaṇa the fifth.[4] He (Lomaharṣaṇa) was (otherwise called) Sūta. He was humble, righteous and pure. His modes of narration were extremely wonderful.

Comment: Vishnu Purana does too;  https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116069.html  Parāśara said:—
" I have related to you this Purāṇa, which is equal to the Vedas in sanctity, "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vayu Purana claims precedence over the Vedas. Brahma first remembered Vayu Purana and Vedas came out after that.

> In the beginning, out of sacred literature, the Purana was remembered
> by Brahma. [1] Then the Vedas came out.

**Vayu Purana I.1.54**

[1] This self-glorificatory claim for precedence over the Vedas is chronologically justifiable as some compilation called Purana did exist before the Atharva Veda (AV XI.7.24, XV.6.11)